# sql query for find open

Tags: sql, select, stock

Given this data set:

```
     Date      |  Itemcode  | Rec or Out | DocType  |  Qty     |
    -----------+------------+-----------------------+----------+
    01/01/2020 |  100011    | Rec        | GRN      | 100      |
    01/01/2020 |  100011    | Out        | FA       |  50      |
    01/01/2020 |  100011    | Out        | FA       |  10      |
    02/02/2020 |  100011    | Out        | FA       |  30      |
    02/02/2020 |  100011    | REC        | GRN      | 100      |
```

I need result, day 2nd opening stock and movement and closing stock'

```
OpeningStock = day 1st (all rec- all out)' 
FA           = day 2nd (all out)' 
GRN          = day 2nd (all rec)'
ClosingStock=  openingstock+GRN-Fa


 Itemcode | OpeningStock | FA | GRN | ClosingStock |
 ---------+--------------+----+-----+--------------+
 100011   |     40       | 30 | 100 | 110          |
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce8e637fe704d4bb44a62b662a788e87)

```
WITH CTE
AS(
    SELECT Itemcode,MIN(Date) MD, 
    (
        SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DocType = 'GRN' THEN Qty ELSE Qty*-1 END) 
        FROM your_table 
        WHERE Itemcode = A.Itemcode
        AND Date = MIN(A.Date)
    ) OS
    FROM your_table A
    GROUP BY Itemcode
)

SELECT B.Itemcode,
MAX(A.OS) OpeningStock ,
SUM(CASE WHEN DocType = 'FA' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) FA,
SUM(CASE WHEN DocType = 'GRN' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) GRN,
MAX(A.OS) +
    SUM(CASE WHEN DocType = 'GRN' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) -
    SUM(CASE WHEN DocType = 'FA' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
AS ClosingStock 
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN your_table B
ON A.MD < B.Date AND A.Itemcode = B.Itemcode
GROUP BY B.Itemcode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function  :

```
select itemcode, rec_qty - Out_qty as OpeningStock, FA, GRN, 
       ((rec_qty - Out_qty) + GRN - FA) as ClosingStock
from(select itemcode, 
            sum(case when seq = 1 and rec = 'rec' then qty end) as rec_qty,
            sum(case when seq = 1 and rec = 'Out' then qty end) as Out_qty,
            sum(case when seq = 2 and rec = 'Out' then qty end) as FA,
            sum(case when seq = 2 and rec = 'rec' then qty end) as grn
     from(select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by itemcode order by date) as seq
          from table t
         ) t
     group by itemcode
    ) t;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, but here where i mention date , because various period find opening and closing stock

Answer (score 0):

You just want a cumulative sum, which is provided using window functions.  You can get the values for all days using:

```
select date, itemcode,
       sum(sum(case when rec = 'Rec' then qty else - qty end)) over
           (partition by itemcode
            order by date
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
           ) as openingstock
       sum(case when doctype = 'FA' then qty end) as fa,
       sum(case when doctype = 'GRN' then qty end) as grn,
       sum(sum(case when rec = 'Rec' then qty else - qty end)) over
           (partition by itemcode order by date) as closingstock
from t
group by date, itemcode;
```

If you want to select a particular date, you can use this as a subquery.